Is PHP Property Comparison Causing Deletion of All Properties on an Object?
I am running into a REALLY odd issue, and my best guess is that it's a bug within PHP itself. When comparing (===) the value of a property on one object with the value of a property on another object, all the values of the properties on one of the objects are deleted.

PHP 8.3.2-1+0~20240120.16+debian11~1.gbpb43448
Laravel Framework 11.4.0
mySQL 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

From the top
I'm editing a Post model, and running the update method on form submit
Routing
Route-model binding works as expected, and the correct controller method is called.
Route::patch('/posts/{id}/update', [PostController::class, 'update'])
        ->name('post.update');

PostController@update
public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, Post $post) :RedirectResponse
{
    // A quick test here that will become relevant in a moment
    // dd(request()->user()->id === $post->user_id); // true

    // Results in 403
    if (request()->user()->cannot('edit', $post)) 
        abort(403);
    .
    .
    .
}

PostPolicy@edit
The PostPolicy class is called to check if the user can edit the post. The if statement is false despite the fact that the values being compared are identical.
/**
 * Determine if "$user" can perform "edit" on "$post"
 */
public function edit(User $user, Post $post) :bool
{
    if ($post->user_id === $user->id) {
        // Expecting this to return
        return $user->can('edit.own_posts');
    }
    else{
        // Always gets returned
        return $user->can('edit.posts');
    }
}

Note: I have verified all roles and permissions are properly assigned, although that isn't really relevant to the issue I'm seeing.
The Problem
In the above function, checking the value of $user and $post BEFORE the if statement yields exactly the values that are expected ... $post->user_id is strictly equal (===) to $user->id.
However, checking the value of $post from within the if statement block, reveals that all the properties on $post are empty. They all just disappeared.
Here are the results of various dd() (dump() and die()) calls.
public function edit(User $user, Post $post) :bool
{
    dd($user->id);                      // int 112
    dd($post->user_id);                 // int 112
    dd($user->id == $post->user_id);    // true
    dd($user->id === $post->user_id);   // true

    // What if accessing the property is what causes it to become null?
    // Let's dump it twice.
    dd($post->user_id, $post->user_id)  // int 112, int 112
    
    // After the comparison, all properties of 
    // $post are empty                              
    if ($post->user_id === $user->id) {

        return $user->can('edit.own_posts');
    }
    else{
        dd($user->id);                      // int 112
        dd($post->user_id);                 // null
        dd($user->id == $post->user_id);    // false
        dd($user->id === $post->user_id);   // false
                                            
        return $user->can('edit.posts');
    }
}

It Gets Weirder
This one is really throwing me off. If, and only if, I place a dd() inside the if block, it will execute as if the comparison resulted in true, but will not execute if I remove the dd().
public function edit(User $user, Post $post) :bool
{
    if ($post->user_id === $user->id) {
        
        // This line executes when present. Removing it will cause
        // the `else` block to execute.
        dd($user->id, $post->user_id);      // int 112, null
        
        return $user->can('edit.own_posts');
    }
    else{
        // This line only executes if you remove the dd() above
        return $user->can('edit.posts');
    }
}

No matter what I do, the second return statement is the only one I can get to. But just for fun, let's try inverting the logic.
public function edit(User $user, Post $post) :bool
{
    if ($post->user_id !== $user->id) {
        // Always executes
        return $user->can('edit.posts');
    }
    else{
        return $user->can('edit.own_posts');
    }
}

For visual reference, here is the dd($post) result before the comparison call.

And here it is again called from within the if block.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before, or have any ideas what could be causing it??

Are you absolutely sure that both of those dumps come from the same request i.e. there's no redirect happening that causes the request to be repeated without any content? Try using dump instead of dd so the request does not stop at the first dd but rather you dump everything (actually the best approach here is to install xdebug and use it in you IDE to enable step debugging so you can see step by step what is happening)

"...if the after callback returns a non-null result that result will be considered the result of the check." -- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#intercepting-gate-checks dd() calls dump() and die() halting execution, then after callback would not be reached.

super personal recommendation, when you need to debug things like this, ALWAYS use xdebug and breakpoints instead of dd because dd stops the execution, and the error could be happening after some iterations that you are not aware of. You can also use dump, but it would take more time for you to debug. I am 99% sure that it is an iteration that you are not aware of, maybe a redirection, as some others already commented, because I can assure you, it is not a PHP bug

We also have no idea if you are using magic methods on the model classes, or if you have scopes or anything around those. It could be ANYTHING getting in between and clearing the post. But, because the post "resets" to a new Post state, I am 99% sure the policy is being executed from a place where you don't have a post, so Laravel resolves (with dependency injection) the post, and it will just do new Post, hence the empty post you see. You may say that you checked that it is not empty before the issue, but again, I am certain that it is another iteration that you are not aware of

One super dirty check you can do before using xdebug, is adding dd(request(), route()); on the else, so you can see the request and route data and get more info, maybe you see the issue on that dump. Just make sure that, when you do this, you do have a request available, but this would also help you check if you are executing this somewhere where you are not aware of, hence the issue

In Policy, the type is sometimes incorrect. Use loose comparisons.
$post->user_id == $user->id

//or
(int) $post->user_id === (int) $user->id

//or
$post->user->is($user)

Even the official Laravel code uses ==.
return $this->id == $team->{$this->getForeignKey()};

https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/30bde139ca1c41d10a58c67f8daa2e8cd3a0be93/src/HasTeams.php#L105

I have tried loose comparisons to no avail. The value of $post->user_id appears to be null, but only when used in the comparison.

I downvoted your answer, and you deserve an explanation because it would also help someone else a little bit. When you say "the type is sometimes incorrect", that is totally not true. The type is always correct, what is not correct is the developer knowledge. The example you shared (github link) is using == because id could be a string instead of an int, so to prevent doing weird checks, just use == and let PHP cast a number (being a string) into an int and pass the check. You should always use ===, but it is a longer discussion that makes no sense to have here

I ran out of characters in my previous message... So, what you answered, has nothing to do with the issue the author is having, what does == or === change to the author about, after the check, having an empty post?
